# How to get an average number of free consumables provided a chance not to consume?

Tags: probability, average, means

Example: I have n consumables and a probability $x_p$ to not use a consumable without losing it, how many free consumables $f(x)$ do I get on average?
My guess is that if you convert the probability $(x_p)$ to odds $(x_o)$, then you can find it by using this equation:
$f(x_o) = nx_o$.
But this is really just an educated guess, and I would really appreciate it if someone knew with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

So when you consume a consumable, you either lose it or not lose it - converting this to "probability terms" , you have $n$ trials where you either succeed or not succeed. The success probability is $x_p$. The number of successes then has a Binomial distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and indeed the mean of this is equal to the number of trials, times the success probability. So I would say that you are correct in your guess.